# amcharts touch&pan event works only after focus

Tags: javascript, touch, amcharts

I'm using amcharts lineChart. when I view it in a tablet it does not respond to touch&pan until I select it first and give it focus. 
When using a pc with a mouse it behaves as expected, i.e. it pans as soon as i click and drag.
Is there any way to fix that?

I've tried setting focus manually `$('.chart-div').focus();` but that does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`tapToActivate`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#tapToActivate) to `false` in your makeChart call to make your chart respond to touch events without tapping first:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  tapToActivate: false,
  // ...
});
```

Comment: dude, you're awesome. thanks once again.. :)
also, again, I wasn't able to find this after ~ 2 hours of googling - the docs are not that easy to get to.
but then again, now there's this questions so i'm guessing it'll be easier to find via google. Thanks!!